# trying to align images in a div

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

Ok, so now I have my boxes all sorted, I would like to try and align an image and some text next to a picture. I would like the text to go at the top and the email logo to go at the bottom as seen on below image

[image: element alignment]

```
#nav1 {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #F90;
}

#pic {
    width: 200px;
    height: 67px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

<div id="container">
    <div id="nav1">
        <div id="pic">
            <img src="email.png" />
            <img src="photo.jpg" align="right" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are serving it like contest questions, that doesn't fit here. You should go thru [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Also you didn't tag your question very well. If you add **html** and **css**, you will get much more visible..

Comment: Why don't you provide an image how you'd like your positioning of images to work because (it may be just me) we can't know what you mean by *I would like the text to go at the top and the email logo to go at the bottom*.

Comment: Can you please provide more details before I try to answer this

Comment: Hey! sorry guys, still getting used to the site, so much so in fact I can't work out how to attach an image. however. if you take a look at your user box (the light blue box with picture,user name, and a couple of numbers below. This is what I'm trying to get.

Comment: figured out the picture thing. Duh. Its now in the question

Comment: you should update your HTML part of the code to reflect your actual HTML because based on the provided image, code seems incomplete. And also according to the image... Is that how it now looks like or is this how you'd like it to look like?

Comment: That's how I would like it to look like. And, what's a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GxHYy/2) with dummy images, that displays information the way that your image shows. Or close to what you want/need.

### HTML

```
<div class="user">
    <img class="avatar" src="http://lorempixel.com/64/64/people"/>    
    <div class="name">Mahatma Gandhi</div>
    <div class="people">6</div>
    <div class="emails">1</div>
</div>​
```

### CSS

```
.user
{
    background-color: #ebebee;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: right;
}
.avatar {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 6px;
}
.name
{
    height: 48px;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    text-align: right;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-right: 70px;
}
.people, .emails
{
    height: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.people { background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/16/16/1); }
.emails { background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/16/16/2); }
​
​
```

Comment: That's great!! thank you so much! I wonder if you could tell me something. I'm trying to code this in Dreamweaver, if I have it on standard view the layout is all over the place, but if I click live view, or preview in browser it all looks correct. Any ideas?

Comment: @user1731516: I updated my answer, because user's avatar was provided as CSS background which would make it problematic to display several users on the same page. I've now added `IMG` element and added some padding around the grey box etc... Regarding DreamWeaver I couldn't say. It must be something with its renderer not being able to properly display this... I don't use it and never liked any HTML editors because of all the crap they add to the resulting HTML when used in designer mode. What was that some... Dog Pro something... HotDog... Some editor that used to be popular long ago.

Comment: Thank you. It was only going to be one user, that would be me, it's a personal website for my design work. Time I left print behind and moved into coding, hence the epic fails in my code. teaching yourself is OK, but having someone to help you along is priceless. Yeah Dreamweaver sucks. handy for beginners like me though :)